# Query for 2 criteria to return one value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table for Mod name, Queue, No of cases, Avg. Handling Time, Productive Hours V1 and Actual Productive Hours.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19KJ6KVBWk2UH21LyPGlqJAml3Nx37ruXCrk9CQrXflE/edit#gid=0

For example: I want a formula to return the number of (Pending calls - EN for the Mod. Kim). I tried Vlook up and query and I don't really know why it's not working.

Excuse my noobness :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=query({ArrayFormula(if(row(C9:C) <= max(if(not(isblank(D9:D)),row(C9:C))),vlookup(row(C9:C),filter({row(C9:C),C9:C},len(C9:C)),2),)), D9:H}, "Select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 = 'Pending calls - EN' and Col1 = 'Kim' group by Col1 label count(Col2)''", 0)
```

or

```
=sumproduct(ArrayFormula(if(row(C9:C) <= max(if(not(isblank(D9:D)),row(C9:C))),vlookup(row(C9:C),filter({row(C9:C),C9:C},len(C9:C)),2),))="Kim", D9:D="Pending calls - EN")
```

and see if that works?

Also see the spreadsheet you shared, cells A1 and A2.

To get the count per 'mod' you can try

```
=query({ArrayFormula(if(row(C9:C) <= max(if(not(isblank(D9:D)),row(C9:C))),vlookup(row(C9:C),filter({row(C9:C),C9:C},len(C9:C)),2),)), D9:H}, "Select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 = 'Pending calls - EN' group by Col1 label count(Col2)''", 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such amazing work. but I still need to return the actual number of cases, like the numbers in column E. what modification would you suggest

Comment: Hi, see A25 for mod Kim and A28 for a sum per mod.

Comment: Sorry one last thing, is it possible to separate the result to be just the number without the Mod. name? cuz i want to put the name of the Mod as a fixed value.

Comment: Assuming the mod name in A25 you can change the select clause to "Select sum(Col3) where Col1 = '"&A25&"' and Col2 = 'Pending calls - EN' and Col1 = 'Kim' group by Col1 label sum(Col3)''". See example in your spreadsheet.